# Large upload issue. php.ini settings are ok, other server issues (cent os, litespeed)?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, centos, litespeed

Am running into a weird issue and I am curious if it is a lower level server config issue we are running into.

We are posting a form that has 1 or more images included.  Normally just 1 image.  We have 2 servers setup.  One is a local vagrant box (ubuntu.  Scotch Box if you are interested) running on my Linux Mint 18 box.  The other system is a cent-os+litespeed server on a physical machine we rent.

Same code, php.ini settings on 2 servers are similar, same image.  I can do it locally, cannot do it over the internet to the cent os server.

Locally, if I upload a 10 mb image, it fails as expected.  On the live server, if I try to upload a 2.4 mb file it fails.

On dev server:

```
post_max_size : 100M
upload_max_filesize : 10M
upload_tmp_dir : /tmp
memory_limit : 512M
max_execution_time : 9999999
max_input_time : 60
```

On local vagrant server:

```
post_max_size : 8M
upload_max_filesize : 10M
upload_tmp_dir : 
memory_limit : 512M
max_execution_time : 9999999
max_input_time : 60
```

I've already looked into this, and commented on it:
[Can't upload large file in Laravel (php.ini settings are correct in my opinion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984580/cant-upload-large-file-in-laravel-php-ini-settings-are-correct-in-my-opinion)

To thicken the plot.  While trying to upload images.  the 2.4 mb image upload fails.  a 1.0 works, a 1.4 mb works, than a 1.2 mb fails?

We are not getting any errors, I watch the post in the dev console and it goes from pending to fail without any details.

Details:

In the env:

```
APP_ENV=dev
APP_DEBUG=true
```

So we should get some sort of error?

Laravel 5.2, Php 5.4.

Not sure if there is any other details?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What do your Apache error logs show when attempting to upload the various image files with different sizes? You can make the logging be more verbose by adding LogLevel with the specific information you want. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel for the different logging levels.